# PhpStorm: change file watcher output location

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have a project that is structured as such

```
project/themes/name/sass
```

And I want to output that Sass to a `css` folder

```
project/themes/name/css
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Go to File > Settings > Tools > File watchers. Select Sass and change the output path

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following setup:

```
Arguments: $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$/themes/name/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/themes/name/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$/themes/name/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map

Working directory: $FileDir$
```

[image]